# Move Specific files from one commit to another in Git?

Tags: git

Let's say we have 2 commits like these :

```
commit id: abz
contain files : a, b and z

commit id: xy
contain files : x and y
```

The question is, is it possible to move file z from abz to xy, if it is, then how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could `cherry-pick` the commit with `abz` files and then unstage all the changes in it and after that add the relevant things and commit a new change

Following is the series of commands that will help you do so:

```
git cherry-pick -n <commit> # get your patch, but don't commit (-n = --no-commit)
git reset                   # unstage the changes from the cherry-picked commit
git add -p                  # add the changes you do want
git commit                  # make the commit!
```

Comment: for the first step, do you mean like this?
git cherry-pick -n abz

Comment: commit-id is the sha commit id, you could get it using git log

Comment: I know, but according to my example it's the abz right? it's just an example, just to make it easier for me to understand :)